# Is there any evidence to suggest Petyr has slept with Catelyn and/or Lysa?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I'm currently partway through ASOS and just read the line by Littlefinger saying:

> "She's had me a few times before, Lord Mathis, and voiced no complaints

I also recall that in ACOK Littlefinger mentions having slept with Catelyn (although that might just be me remembering wrong).

I was wondering whether there is evidence that Littlefinger did in fact sleep with one or the other, or whether it's just a ploy to convince the Council to play along in his grand scheme?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Catelyn

Littlefinger has definitely NOT slept with Catelyn.

Early in *A Game of Thrones* when Cat is traveling with Ser Roderick to King's Landing, the two have a discussion that Ser Roderick should be the one to go ashore and find the person they are looking because there are some people who may recognize Catelyn.

Catelyn knows who this means... Petyr Baelish. She tells Ser Roderick that the two of them were raised at Riverrun together and Petyr had developed a unrequited love for Catelyn. He even went as far as to challenge Brandon Stark (Ned's older brother) to a duel. Petyr lost this encounter and was sent away from Riverrun. Catelyn was 15 and this was the last time she saw Petyr until her arrival at King's Landing.

Any suggestions that these two were intimate are misleading and false.

---

## Lysa

Putting this in spoilers because, you may not have reached this part of ASOS yet...

> As part of Littlefinger's plot to climb the ladder of power he decides to marry Lysa. Their marriage is definitely consummated...

> Lysa also has words with Petyr:
>
> *"... I've always loved you. I've proved it, haven't I? I gave you my maiden's gift. I would have given you a son too..."*
>
> *"Cat never gave you anything. It was me who got you your first post..."*
>
> *"Catelyn kissed you in the godswood, but she never meant it, she never wanted you. Why did you love her best? It was me, it was always meeee!"*

So clearly the two have been intimate before at least on a few occasions...

There is also a related question [(here)](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37160/who-is-lord-hoster-tullys-tansy/37162#37162) that implies:

> Petyr got Lysa pregnant during one their encounters.

(Thanks to @Edlothiad for the connection)

Comment: I just read the same thing [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/37160/who-is-lord-hoster-tullys-tansy/37162#37162) where someone asks what `Tansy` was, and the answer uses a quote to describe a conversation where  [WARNING SPOILERS OF ASOS PART 2] 
Lysa talks about drinking something her father gave her and accidentally aborting her and Petyr's child.

Comment: I don't remember where exactly but I think I remember reading that Lysa dressed up as Catelyn and fooled Petyr into sleeping with her, so he thought he had slept with Catelyn until Lysa told him the truth years later

Comment: This reminds me of the rule of three.

Comment: Who is this Peytr Baselich that you speak of?

Comment: “There is also a related question (here) that implies Peytr got Lysa pregnant during one their encounters.” — So Robyn Arryn might actually be a Little Littlefinger?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite There's no evidence for Robert Arryn being Littlefinger's afaik. That refers to Lysa being pregnant and being tricked/forced into aborting the baby before her marriage to Jon Arryn.

Answer (score 12):

#### Petyr Baelish's claims

You're not wrong in remembering that, Petyr did boast of bedding the Tully girls at court. Both Tyrion and Jaime threw that in face of Catelyn Stark:

In ACOK Jaime said:

> Jaime took a swallow, wiped his mouth. “**No doubt Ned wished to spare
>   you. His sweet young bride, if not quite a maiden.** Well, you wanted
>   truth. Ask me. We made a bargain, I can deny you nothing. Ask.”

He also said:

> “That name again. I don’t think I’ll f--k you after all, **Littlefinger**
>   **had you first, didn’t he?** I never eat off another man’s trencher.
>   Besides, you’re not half so lovely as my sister.”

Unlike his brother however, Tyrion believed it to be a lie:

> “Why does a bear shit in the woods?” he demanded. “Because it is his
>   nature. Lying comes as easily as breathing to a man like Littlefinger.
>   You ought to know that, you of all people.”
>
> She took a step toward him, her face tight. “And what does that mean,
>   Lannister?”
>
> Tyrion cocked his head. “**Why, every man at court has heard him tell
>   how he took your maidenhead, my lady**.”

#### The proof for authenticity and falsehood of his claims

The other answers have successfully established that:

> Petyr had indeed slept with Lysa and impregnated her. He however did
>  not sleep with Catelyn.

One thing that has not been discussed is that Petyr Baelish quite genuinely believes to have bedded both of them. So when he talks about bedding them both, he actually believes it to be true.

Petyr Baelish was brought to Riverrun when Lord Hoster befriended Petyr's father in a military campaign. The Tully girls actually did things in Childhood which lead Petyr on. From AGOT Chapter 71:

> How young they all had been-she no older than Sansa, Lysa younger than
>   Arya, and Petyr younger still, yet eager. **The girls had traded him
>   between them, serious and giggling by turns**. It came back to her so
>   vividly she could almost feel his sweaty fingers on her shoulders and
>   taste the mint on his breath. There was always mint growing in the
>   godswood, and Petyr had liked to chew it. He had been such a bold
>   little boy, always in trouble. “He tried to put his tongue in my
>   mouth,” Catelyn had confessed to her sister afterward, when they were
>   alone. “He did with me too,” Lysa had whispered, shy and breathless.
>   “I liked it.”

Then in ASOS Chapter 45 Catelyn recalls this:

> She had played at being Jenny that day, had even wound flowers in her
>  hair. And Petyr had pretended to be her Prince of Dragonflies. Catelyn
>  could not have been more than twelve, Petyr just a boy.

Prince of Dragonflies, Duncan "The Small" Targaryen and his lady wife Jenny of Oldstone were Westerosi version of a celebrated couple of lovers like Romeo and Juliet in our world. Sure they were kids back then and Catelyn never meant anything by these gestures but they lead Petyr on a road where he ultimately fell in love with her (At least back then he did).

Then Lysa Tully recalls the Night of Catelyn's betrothal to Brandon Stark in ASOS Chapter 80:

> “Be quiet, I haven’t given you leave to speak. **You enticed him, just
>  as your mother did that night in Riverrun**, with her smiles and her
>  dancing. You think I could forget? **That was the night I stole up to
>  his bed to give him comfort. I bled, but it was the sweetest hurt. He
>  told me he loved me then, but he called me Cat, just before he fell
>  back to sleep**. Even so, I stayed with him until the sky began to
>  lighten."

Petyr Baelish was "heartbroken" if we assume he had a heart back then, when Catelyn laughed at him and rejected his attempts to kiss her again. He was drunk when Lysa slipped into his room. They slept together but Petyr believed it was Catelyn who came to him that night, not Lysa<sup>1</sup>. So that's why Petyr Baelish believes he bedded both the Tully sisters and tells other people about it so confidently that even Tyrion could not be sure who is lying? Petyr or Catelyn?

In the same Chapter Lysa recalls:

> Everyone thought it [Petyr's expulsion from Riverrun] was because of
>  that stupid duel with Brandon Stark, but that wasn’t so. Father said I
>  ought to thank the gods that **so great a lord as Jon Arryn was
>  willing to take me soiled**, but I knew it was only for the swords. I
>  had to marry Jon, or my father would have turned me out as he did his
>  brother, but it was Petyr I was meant for. I am telling you all this
>  so you will understand how much we love each other, how long we have
>  suffered and dreamed of one another. **We made a baby together, a
>  precious little baby.**

Catelyn on the other hands always did her duty as charged by her Lord Father. She had never liked Petyr and she was content with her betrothal to heir to Winterfell, Brandon Stark. Later when Brandon died, She had accepted that she had to marry Eddard Stark instead. And as DariM has already quoted:

> And when Brandon was murdered and father told me I must wed his
>   brother, I did so gladly, though I never saw Ned's face until our
>   wedding day. **I gave my maidenhood to this solemn stranger[Eddard Stark]** and sent
>   him off to his war and his king and the women who bore him his
>   bastard, because I always did my duty.

---

<sub>**1**</sub>  <sub>It is unclear that Lysa ever told Petyr that it was her who came to him that night, not Catelyn. It is also unclear if Petyr ever told Lysa that he believed that it was Catelyn despite uttering her name after having sex. It is possible that Lysa may have told Petyr about that night and since Petyr knew Lysa had to abort the child he left her with, it becomes more plausible that she did. Which would essentially mean that Petyr knew and had been lying deliberately. Nevertheless, since it is my observation, not canon info, I'd dance with what's provided in the canon sources</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Catelyn confirms that she has not slept with Littlefinger in an inner monologue in *A Clash of Kings*:

> *I gave Brandon my favor to wear, and never went to Petyr once after he was wounded, nor bid him farewell when father sent him off. And
>   when Brandon was murdered and father told me I must wed his brother, I
>   did so gladly, though I never saw Ned's face until our wedding day. **I
>   gave my maidenhood to this solemn stranger** and sent him off to his war
>   and his king and the women who bore him his bastard, because I always
>   did my duty.*

There's zero reason to believe this is anything other than the truth. She isn't actually speaking or filtering the words, it's a direct thought going on in her head. She was still a virgin when she married Ned, and Littlefinger had already been sent away from Riverrun.

As far as Lysa goes, Skooba also provided the relevant quote in his answer that confirm she did sleep with him, but here it is:

> ... I've always loved you. I've proved it, haven't I?"
>  
>  Tears ran down her aunt's puffy red face.   "I gave you my maiden's
>  gift. I would have given you a son too, but they murdered him with
>  moon tea, with .....